# Importing Python classes (__init__.py problems)

Tags: python, import, module

I'm having problems importing Python modules from my project folder into tests folder. Sure I'm missing something, but having read lots of other answers I still can't get it to work.

Folder structure is as follows:

```
/CorpusBuilder
    /corpusBuilder
        __init__.py
        corpus.py    # contains Corpus class
   /tests
       __init__.py
       test_corpus.py   # trying to import Corpus class — but fails
```

Exactly what should be the content of each `__init__.py` file? [Does the top level folder (`CorpusBuilder`) need an `__init__.py` file as well?] What should the `import` statement in `test_corpus.py` say?

Sorry for so many questions: I think I just need a clear example to work from.

Comment: In terms of getting a project set up, see e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put anything at all into the `__init__.py` files. Assuming you're running your tests from the base "CorpusBuilder" directory, or otherwise have put that directory onto the PYTHONPATH, your test_corpus file can simply say `from corpusBuilder.corpus import Corpus`.

Comment: From the base 'CorpusBuilder' directory, I'm running `$ python test/test_corpus.py` (which contains `from corpusBuilder.corpus import Corpus`) and still get the same error. Do I also have to add directory to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I've also tried adding a `__init__.py` file to the base "CorpusBuilder" directory. I just get an error saying  `ImportError: No module named corpusBuilder.corpus`

Answer (score 0):

In my approach (according to http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/index.html) tests is not at top-level. And no need for an init file there. (assuming the name of your module shall be corpusBuilder). What you will need is a setup.py (again: http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/minimal.html and https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) if you want to run you tests with:

```
$ python setup.py test
```

so your structure should be:

```
CorpusBuilder/
    corpusBuilder/
        corpus.py
        __init__.py
        tests/
           __init__.py
           test_corpus.py
    setup.py
    ...
```

in corpusBuilder's init you can define imports from submodules. This is useful to not pollute your namespace. For example:

```
from .submodule import foo
```

Otherwise, this is just a blank file.

The init file in

```
tests/
```

doesn't need anything at all and in your test_corpus you need to import your module. For example:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import corpusBuilder

class TestOne(TestCase):
    def test_ist_string(self):
        s = minimal.test()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(s, basestring))
```

You should be able to run your tests now.